# Switching active states of two GameObjects in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cardboard

With Unity3D I am trying to create a scene with an alpha texture as a silhouette, which upon looking up is added, then looking down removes.

Currently I have the exposure of an equirectangular image changing on look up, but my silhouette object says I have not assigned it to an instance:

[image]

[image]

As you can see from the console, it is eventualy recognised, but I cannot set the active state. This is the current state of my code being applied to the scene:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class switchScript : MonoBehaviour {

    public Cardboard cb;

    public Renderer leftEyeDay;

    public Renderer rightEyeDay;

    private GameObject[] dayObjects;

    public GameObject nightObject;

    void Start () {
        MeshFilter filter = GetComponent(typeof (MeshFilter)) as MeshFilter;

        if (filter != null) {
            Mesh mesh = filter.mesh;

            Vector3[] normals = mesh.normals;
            for (int i=0;i<normals.Length;i++)
                normals[i] = -normals[i];
            mesh.normals = normals;

            for (int m=0;m<mesh.subMeshCount;m++)
            {
                int[] triangles = mesh.GetTriangles(m);
                for (int i=0;i<triangles.Length;i+=3)
                {
                    int temp = triangles[i + 0];
                    triangles[i + 0] = triangles[i + 1];
                    triangles[i + 1] = temp;
                }
                mesh.SetTriangles(triangles, m);
            }
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        float xAngle = cb.HeadPose.Orientation.eulerAngles.x;

        if (isLookingUp (xAngle)) {
            var exposureValue = getExposureValue (xAngle);
            leftEyeDay.material.SetFloat ("_Exposure", exposureValue);
            rightEyeDay.material.SetFloat ("_Exposure", exposureValue);
            toggleNight ();
        } else {
            leftEyeDay.material.SetFloat ("_Exposure", 1F);
            rightEyeDay.material.SetFloat ("_Exposure", 1F);
            toggleNight ();
        }
    }

    public bool isLookingUp (float xAngle) {
        return xAngle > 270 && xAngle < 340;
    }

    public float getExposureValue (float xAngle) {
        var _xAngle = Mathf.Clamp (xAngle, 320, 340);
        return ScaleValue (320.0F, 340.0F, 0.3F, 1.0F, _xAngle);
    }

    public float ScaleValue (float from1, float to1, float from2, float to2, float v) {
        return from2 + (v - from1) * (to2 - from2) / (to1 - from1);
    }

    void toggleDay() {

        print (nightObject);

        nightObject = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Night");

        nightObject.SetActive (false);

    }

    void toggleNight() {

        print (nightObject);

        nightObject = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Night");

        nightObject.SetActive (true);

    }

}
```

Comment: you toggle ***components*** using .enabled.  you toggle ***whole game objects*** using SetActive.  it's a real "gotchya" in unity, very annoying!

Answer (score 0):

GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Night") returns null when the whole object is set to !active. Just toggle the scripts on that object instead of the whole GO.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if anyone needs this, this is an easy way to create scene switch:

```
void Awake() {

        silhouetteObject = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag ("Night");

        silhouetteObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().enabled = false;
    }
```